# Search tasks by tags in Mobileorg Android

Tags: org-mode, org-export, mobileorg

I'm trying to use Mobileorg in android. Mobileorg syncs well with my Dropbox. The org files staged are captured well by mobileorg. However I'm having trouble searching for tasks based on tags.

Providing only tag name (ex: Project1) or with colons (:Project1:), the search tells me no results found.